# How do I display an xml file properly?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm pretty new to this so I'm a little helpless when it comes to solving an issue such as this. I'm trying to figure out how can I display a file *`order.xml`* properly. I am coding in C#.

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Order>
<Items orderId="4001">
<orderDate>22/05/2015</orderDate>
<buyerId>85852020</buyerId>
  <item itemId="8002">
    <itemName>LCD Screen</itemName>
    <desc>Component used for computer displays</desc>
    <quantity>20</quantity>
    <unitPrice>110.40</unitPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemId="8010">
    <itemName>Cooling Fan</itemName>
    <desc>Cools computer components</desc>
    <quantity>50</quantity>
    <unitPrice>65.50</unitPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemId= "8030">
    <itemName>Keyboard</itemName>
    <desc>Facilitates text input into computer</desc>
    <quantity>50</quantity>
    <unitPrice>25.90</unitPrice>
  </item>
</Items>
```

and this is my program code, the method `DisplayOrder()` in *`program.cs`* that is trying to list out the order in the console:

```
    private static void DisplayOrder()
    {
        // Get a list of all XmlNodes with the tag Contact
        XmlNodeList orderList = orderDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Items");
        Console.WriteLine("Displaying the Orders... \r\n");
        StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (XmlNode node in orderList)
        {
            list.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            if (node.Attributes.Count > 0)
                list.Append("Order ID = ").Append(
                    node.Attributes[0].Value).Append(Environment.NewLine);
            if (node.HasChildNodes)
            {
                XmlElement childNode = (XmlElement)node.FirstChild;
                for (int idx = 0; idx < node.ChildNodes.Count; idx++)
                {
                    switch (childNode.Name)
                    {
                        //case "orderId":
                        //    list.Append("Order ID = ");
                        //    break;
                        case "orderDate":
                            list.Append("Order Date = ");
                            break;
                        case "buyerId":
                            list.Append("Buyer ID = ");
                            break;
                        case "itemId":
                            list.Append("Item ID = ");
                            break;
                        case "itemName":
                            list.Append("Item Name = ");
                            break;
                        case "desc":
                            list.Append("Description = ");
                            break;
                        case"quantity":
                            list.Append("Quantity = ");
                            break;
                        case "unitPrice":
                            list.Append("Existing Unit Price = ");
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    list.Append(childNode.InnerText).Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    childNode = (XmlElement)childNode.NextSibling;
                }
            }
            list.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(list);
    }
}
```

Therefore, my main problem is that I am unsure of how I am able change the outcome of the output in the console, as seen below:

```
    Displaying the Orders...

    Order ID = 4001
    Order Date = 22/05/2015
    Buyer ID = 85852020
    LCD ScreenComponent used for computer displays20110.40
    Cooling FanCools computer components5065.50
    KeyboardFacilitates text input into computer5025.90
```

The 'items' are not listed as I would like them to. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

The expected output is

```
    Displaying the Orders...

    Order ID = 4001
    Order Date = 22/05/2015
    Buyer ID = 85852020

    Item Name = LCD Screen
    Description = Component used for computer displays
    Quantity = 20
    Price = 110.40

    Item Name = Cooling Fan
    Description = Cools computer components
    Quantity = 50
    Price = 65.50

    Item Name = Keyboard
    Description = Facilitates text input into computer
    Quantity = 50
    Price = 25.90
```

Comment: And how would you like them to be output?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: I've just added in the expected output. If it is of any help, I'm trying to use the DOM approach to read the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about how you would like this to be output, and using LINQ to XML as it's generally a nicer API than the old `XmlDocument` API:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var orderId = (string)doc.Descendants("Items")
    .Select(e => e.Attribute("orderId"))
    .Single();
var orderDate = (string)doc.Descendants("orderDate").Single();
var buyerId = (string)doc.Descendants("buyerId").Single();

Console.WriteLine("Order ID: {0}", orderId);
Console.WriteLine("Order Date: {0}", orderDate);
Console.WriteLine("Buyer ID: {0}", buyerId);

foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("item"))
{
    var id = (string)item.Attribute("itemId");
    var name = (string)item.Element("itemName");
    var description = (string)item.Element("desc");
    var quantity = (int)item.Element("quantity");
    var price = (decimal)item.Element("unitPrice");

    Console.WriteLine("---");
    Console.WriteLine("Item ID: {0}", id);
    Console.WriteLine("Item Name: {0}", name);
    Console.WriteLine("Item Description: {0}", description);
    Console.WriteLine("Item Quantity: {0}", quantity);
    Console.WriteLine("Item Price: {0}", price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you do not want the whole `<item ....` content to be displayed at all? This comes from the line `list.Append(childNode.InnerText) ...` without any of the case labels matching. Try:

```
default:
   continue;
```

In the hope, it actually skips this iteration of the `for` loop..